# Unity target position never stops with Vector3.SmoothDamp

Tags: unity, animation, unityscript, tweening

I've integrated `Vector3.SmoothDamp` method to have a more fluid and native movement between the character and his camera in Unity. The camera movement is perfectly in sync with the character because both uses `SmoothDamp` to move, but the character sometimes still looking for the final position in the `x` axes.

[image: The character still going forward lightly when right key is now pressed]

How can I fix the problem introduced by `SmoothDamp` without remove it?
The problem seems to be correlated to `targetPosition.x` which still changes but I'm not sure why because `hrxMovement` and `velocity.x` reaches `0`:

```
float movementDuration = 0.3f;
float movementSpeed = 2.5f;

void Run () {
    float hrzMovement = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    Vector2 velocity = new Vector2(Vector2.right.x * movementSpeed * hrzMovement, body.velocity.y);
    Vector3 targetPosition = new Vector3(body.transform.position.x + hrzMovement, body.transform.position.y, body.transform.position.z);

    body.transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(body.transform.position, targetPosition, ref transformVelocity, movementDuration);

    print("hrzMovement: " + hrzMovement + ", velocity.x: " + velocity.x + ", targetPosition.x: " + targetPosition.x);

    if (velocity.x != 0) {
        animation.SetBool("isMoving", true);
        orientationMovement = velocity.x;
    } else {
        animation.SetBool("isMoving", false);
    }

    if (orientationMovement < 0) {
        body.transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1, 1, 1);
    } else {
        body.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
    }

}
```

#### Additional packages used:

I'm using [Pixel Perfect Camera](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/64563) package, I hope this doesn't affect the code.

Comment: How much is movementDuration?

Comment: I've update the code, i've set it to `float movementDuration = 0.3f;`

Comment: It looks like you have a Rigidbody2D attached here, but you're moving it by setting its `transform.position`. This can cause a number of artifacts and performance impacts as the Rigidbody and Transform components fight for control. You may get smoother & more controllable results if you route all movement through the body, either by steering its velocity or by using MovePosition(). I can't say whether that's the root cause without seeing more about what the body is doing & what's affecting it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, there are tons of ways to do the same thing and sometimes video tutorials suggests wrong things for the same lack of information, I'll fix it.

Answer (score -1):

I've found a solution by adding a condition which removes decimals to be easy to be reached but I loose movements precision I wouldn't loose.

```
Vector3 targetPosition = new Vector3(body.transform.position.x + hrzMovement, body.transform.position.y, body.transform.position.z);

if (Mathf.Approximately(body.transform.position.x, targetPosition.x)) {
    targetPosition = new Vector3((float)Math.Round((double)body.transform.position.x, 1), body.transform.position.y, body.transform.position.z);
}
```

Maybe there is some smartest way to keep movement precision?